# How to print 3rd from bottom line in file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to read and print the 3rd from last line in date.log.  This is specified in the line_from_bottom_line variable.
The log can have any number of lines at any time.

Here is an example of what the log looks like:

```
192.168.80.231 May 8 2018 18:45:00
192.168.80.231 July 30 2018 09:46:48
192.168.80.231 July 2 2018 14:37:14
```

If there are only 3 lines in the log, the else line will be printed:

```
 line_number[x1] = [(index,log_time)]
```

The output will be:

```
(1, '18:45:00')
```

Which is not what I want.

If there are 4 or more lines, the line printed will be in the format of:

```
2018:8:18:45:00
```

This is what I want.

I think my code below is moving to the bottom line and subtracting 3. So if 4 lines don't exist, it doesn't know
what to print.  How can I change it so that the 3rd from bottom line is printed even if there are not 4 or more 
lines in the log?

```
old_time = (line_number[x1][-(line_from_bottom_line)].__str__())

from datetime import datetime, date, time

# this would be the third from last line
line_from_bottom_line = 3

date_order  = 2
time_order  = 4
year_order  = 3

present = datetime.now()

def main():
    logfile = open('krinkov.log', 'r+')
    line_number = dict()
    for index,line in enumerate(logfile,1):  # scan lines
        if line in ['\n', '\r\n']:  # Error Checking: if not enough lines in var .log
            print("Not enough lines.")
            return
        if line:
            x1 = line.split()[0]  # if line, get IP address
            log_day   = line.split()[date_order]
            log_time  = line.split()[time_order]  # This will already be in the format of hh:mm:ss
            log_year  = line.split()[year_order]
        if x1 in line_number :  # if ip address on line
            line_number[x1].append((log_year + ":" + log_day + ":" + log_time))

        else:
            line_number[x1] = [(index,log_time)]

    if x1 in line_number and len(line_number.get(x1,None)) > 1:

        # Below is where I am having issues.
        # If there are not 4 or more lines in the log, an error occurs.
        old_time = (line_number[x1][-line_from_bottom_line])
        print(old_time)

        # ** get last line number.  Print that line number.  then subtract 2 from it
        # old_time = that new number


    else:
        print('Nothing')
main()
```

Comment: Why using python? A simple `tail -n3 your_file.txt | head -n1` in the console will do that

Comment: Don't call `obj.__str__()`. The `__` gernerally indicate that you're not supposed to call this method from the outside. Instead, use `str(obj)`. But your print-statement does that already, so you can drop this entirely.

Comment: You also don't need brackets around the `2`, `line_number[x1][-2]` will suffice.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to use         old_time = (line_number[x1][-line_from_bottom_line])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** Look at where you add new elements to your `line_number` dictionary:

```
if x1 in line_number :  # if ip address on line
    line_number[x1].append((log_year + ":" + log_day + ":" + log_time))

else:
    line_number[x1] = [(index,log_time)]
```

If the dictionary does *not* contain the IP address yet (i.e. the `else` part gets executed), you create the IP field with a dictionary containing a list with the element `(index,log_time)`, which is a tuple with two elements.

After that, if the IP address is already contained (the `if` part gets executed), you only add `(log_year + ":" + log_day + ":" + log_time)`, i.e. the **string** `log_year + ":" + log_day + ":" + log_time`. That's because `(elem)` in Python gets unpacked to `elem`. If you want to create a tuple containing a single element, you have to write `(elem,)`.

Considering this, it seems likeevery value in your `line_number` dictionary will look something like this (check this!):

```
[(1, '18:45:00'), "2018:8:18:45:00", "2018:8:18:45:00", "2018:8:18:45:00" ... ]
```

**Fix:** changing `[(index,log_time)]` in the above excerpt to `[(log_year + ":" + log_day + ":" + log_time)]` should fix your problem. It's bad coding style though because you're writing the same thing twice. A better solution would be to replace the above code with the following line:

```
line_number[x1] = line_number.get(x1, []) + [f"{log_year}:{log_day}:{log_time}"]
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have caught that. haha

Comment: Your welcome. As a tip, inserting some `print()` statements here and there can clarify what's going on. A debugger is even better at this ;)